# Setting up umbraco

Tags: iis, umbraco

hello i am trying to set up umbraco on my pc

i have followed each step

and when i try to lunch the site on iis i get this error

Module IIS Web Core 
Notification BeginRequest 
Handler Not yet determined 
Error Code 0x80070032 
Config Error The configuration section 'system.web.extensions' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration
Config File \?\C:\inetpub\wwwroot\cms\web.config 
Requested URL http://localhost:80/cms 
Physical Path C:\inetpub\wwwroot\cms 
Logon Method Not yet determined 
Logon User Not yet determined

any idea? please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the version of .NET that the application pool is running under.

You've not mentioned which version of Umbraco you are using but I'm guessing 4.7.

If so you'll probably need to be running it under .NET4, unless you have specifically downloaded the .NET3.5 version direct from Codeplex.

Answer (score 0):

try to change the port to other number rather than using default 80 port.
hope this helps